# Telerik Line Charts not displaying line on IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have been using Telerik Charts with Asp.net mvc and I have run into a bit of a weird problem. I cant get the lines on a line chart to show up on IE9. It works on all other browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Safari and even IE 7 and 8). I have never run into such a problem before. Any help would be appreciated. This is what my code looks like

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Chart<AllStars.Models.Charts.MyChart>()
       .Name("chart1")
       .Legend(legend => legend
           .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
       )
       .Series(series => {
            series.Line(s => s.value1).Name("Value1").Color("#26a0db");
            series.Line(s => s.value2).Name("Value2").Color("#009900");
            series.Line(s => s.value3).Name("Value3").Color("#E4814F");
        })
       .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .Categories(o => o.title)
            .Labels(l => l.Rotation(-45))
       )
       .ValueAxis(axis => axis
            .Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:#,##0}%"))
       )
       .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("<#= series.name #> : <#= value #>")
       )
       .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
            .Ajax().Select("DrawChart", "Charts")
       )
       .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 840px; height: 400px;"})
%>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If not, do any errors show up in the error console? Link on how to use IE9's error console, in case you need it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K figured out the problem. Since I had the grid within a tabstrip, telerik had some weird thing where it wouldnt show lines with transitions while it is within a tabstrip. It is definitely a telerik bug, but disabling the transitions makes the lines show up again.